# Cannot build SBT project with Scala 2.12.8

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I created a simple scala SBT application in IntelliJ. I have Scala 2.12.8 (the newest) and SBT 1.2.7. Java jdk in path is 9 and in project structure 8. I got this error while building it:
Error while importing sbt project:

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 487
    Exception Details:
    Location:
    scala/reflect/internal/Types.appliedType(Lscala/reflect/internal/Types$Type;Lscala/collection/immutable/List;)Lscala/reflect/internal/Types$Type; @545: goto
    Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
    Bytecode:
    0000000: 2cb6 02dd 9900 052b b003 3606 013a 072b
    0000010: c101 7899 0075 0436 062b c001 783a 0719
   ...
```

I tried to change jdk to 10 and it didn't work. I've also tried to change scala version for older (2.11.12) and it also did not help. Anyone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3516 ? Check your JAVA_HOME settings and use command line `java -version` to verify SBT is really running using Java 8 or newer.

Comment: Yes. My JAVA_HOME is jdk 10.0.2. When I use java -version I got Java 9. Dont know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. In IntelliJ, sbt configuration was set to JRE 1.8. I changed it to jdk 10 and finally project built.

Comment: This is quite strange. SBT 1.x.x should work fine using Java 8. It is only Java 7 or older which is not compatible.

Comment: Yes it is. But this configuration pointed to JRE 1.8, no JDK 1.8. Maybe it was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the JDK is your PATH environment variable pointing to? If its pointing to an older version of the JDK, that may be the cause.

Comment: Yes. My JAVA_HOME is jdk 10.0.2

Comment: Can you run java -version?

Comment: Hmm, 9.0.4. Dont know why.